# Select only duplicates from a 3 table join

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates, many-to-many

I have a table like this

`comptitle,trknum,cdtitle
"A-Tisket, A-Tasket",4,Swing
Choo Choo Ch' Boogie,13,Swing
Clouds,10,Swing
Countdown,11,Giant Steps
Countdown,3,Giant Steps
Cousin Mary,10,Giant Steps
Cousin Mary,14,Swing
Cousin Mary,2,Giant Steps
Down South Camp Meetin',8,Swing
Giant Steps,1,Giant Steps
Giant Steps,8,Giant Steps
I Know Why,5,Swing
It's a Good Enough to Keep,12,Swing
Java Jive,7,Swing
Mr. P.C.,7,Giant Steps
Naima,6,Giant Steps
Naima,9,Giant Steps
Sing a Study in Brown,2,Swing
Sing Moten's Swing,3,Swing
Sing You Sinners,6,Swing
Skyliner,11,Swing
Spiral,4,Giant Steps
Stomp of King Porter,1,Swing
Syeeda's Song Flute,12,Giant Steps
Syeeda's Song Flute,5,Giant Steps
Topsy,9,Swing`

Which I got from this query

`SELECT comptitle, trknum, cdtitle from composition
  join track on track.compid = composition.compid
  join cd on cd.cdid = track.cdid
  group by  comptitle, trknum, cdtitle
  order by comptitle, trknum;`

I only want to show the rows where comptitle (the first column) is a duplicate, so the result should be this

`comptitle,trknum,cdtitle
Countdown,11,Giant Steps
Countdown,3,Giant Steps
Cousin Mary,10,Giant Steps
Cousin Mary,14,Swing
Cousin Mary,2,Giant Steps
Giant Steps,1,Giant Steps
Giant Steps,8,Giant Steps
Naima,6,Giant Steps
Naima,9,Giant Steps
Syeeda's Song Flute,12,Giant Steps
Syeeda's Song Flute,5,Giant Steps`

I've tried using count, but `having count(comptitle) > 1` returns every row instead of just the ones with duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not mistaken, table `track` stores the number of track per composition. In this case, you can create a subquery that gets the `compid` having multiple tracks,

```
SELECT 
    comptitle, trknum, cdtitle 
FROM
    composition
JOIN
    track ON track.compid = composition.compid
JOIN 
    cd ON cd.cdid = track.cdid
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT compid
     FROM track
     GROUP BY compid
     HAVING COUNT(compid) > 1) cc ON composition.compid = cc.compid
GROUP BY
    comptitle, trknum, cdtitle
ORDER BY 
    comptitle, trknum;
```

This query can still be simplified, in my opinion, if you will give us the relationship of each table and sample records.